# How save results from different orders of ARMA-GARCH model?

Tags: r

I want to see AIC and BIC values of ARMA-GARCH models in a table. I created a loop which creates a dataframe and then merges it with already created table (`rbind()`). However, the loop is running too slowly, I read that it is better (speed reason) to store dataframe in a `list()`. Could you help to find a way how to quickly store the results? I think there should be `scores <- list()`, but do not where to put and in what ranges (the number of possible order combinations) should additional loop to be created.

```
scores <- data.frame()
for (s in 1:5) {
  for (r in 1:5) {
    for (p in 1:5) {
      for (q in 1:5) {
        
          spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(s, r)), 
                     mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(p,q), include.mean = TRUE), distribution.model = "std")
          Sup_fit <- ugarchfit(spec, MYVALUES)
          results <- data.frame(aic = infocriteria(Sup_fit)[1],
                                bic = infocriteria(Sup_fit)[2],
                                hq = infocriteria(Sup_fit)[4],
                                garch_arch = paste0(1,",",1,"_",1,",",1))
          scores <- rbind(scores, results)
           
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

UPDATE:
I changed the code (added vector list) in order to speed up the process, however it is also slow

```
library(tidyr)
b <- as.matrix(crossing(s = 1:5, r = 1:5, p = 1:5, q = 1:5))
aic <- vector("list", length(b[,1]))

for (i in 1:length(b[,1])) {
  spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(b[,1][i], b[,2][i])), 
                     mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(b[,3][i],b[,4][i]), include.mean = TRUE), distribution.model = "std")
  Sup_fit <- ugarchfit(spec, Sup_values)
  #a$aic[i] <- infocriteria(Sup_fit)[1]
  aic[i] <- infocriteria(Sup_fit)[1]
}

output <- do.call(rbind, aic)
```

Comment: You can have combinations of s, r, p, q as a separate data frame, the model specification up to scores as a function and use `apply` function to loop.

Comment: I updated, however the speed seems not to be much faster